# Determine variable type within django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a variable that I'm pulling into a table that sometimes is a date and sometimes is a string.  If the variable is a date, I want to change the formatting:

```
<td>{{ action.extra_column|date:"M d" }}</td>
```

But if it is a string, I just want to display it as is:

```
<td>{{ action.extra_column }}</td>
```

If I try to format it and it is a string, I get no output for the variable.

How can I determine the type so that I can adjust my rendering based on type.

Comment: it depends on the variable that is being passed.  To be honest, this is a bit of a simplification.  The views.py passes an array that has a variable "extra_column."  Think of this like a characteristic of the "action."  Depending on the context of the template, I want to show the date for the action, or I might want to show detail for the action. So it is always action.extra_column, but this extra_column might be a date or might be a string.

Comment: I think you need to include more code in your question, like the line(s) from your view defining `action`. It sounds like you are trying to put too much logic in the template. In general, just make sure your view passes your template the right data and you shouldn't have to do much work to make sure it comes out in HTML correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams pointed out in the first comment, that's not really a great way to code your logic. I would ensure that your variable has a certain type. That could be solved through an additional variable you add to the context or an object that holds the data and something that describes the type of data.

If you want to stick to your logic, a possible approach would be to write your own template filter (let's call it `date_or_string`). The filter could subclass the builtin `date` filter with the format parameter being optional. In case the parameter is passed it works like the normal `date` filter, without the parameter it simply returns the string. In a more complex scenario the filter could also do some type checking. Just an idea, i wouldn't actually put that kind of logic into the template.

Answer (score 42):

You could also implement a general template filter as an equivalent to the `type()` builtin:

```
# app/templatetags/util.py
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_type(value):
    return type(value)

# template.html
{% load util %}
{% if extra_column|get_type == 'str' %}
    String
{% elif extra_column|get_type == 'datetime.date' %}
    Date
{% else %}
    Oh no!
{% endif %}
```

I think Ignacio and Dirk are right, however. Can't you just have two keys (you say "array", but I assume you mean "dictionary" from the fact that the items have names) called `date` and `detail`?

```
# views.py
...
actions = [{
    'some_property': 'some_value'
    'date': None,
    'detail': 'details'
},
{
    'some_property': 'some_value'
    'date': datetime.date.today(),
    'detail': None
}]
...

# template.html
{% for action in actions %}
<td>{% if action.date %}{{ action.date|date:"M d" }}{% endif %}{{ action.detail }}</td>
{% endfor %}

# output
<td>details</td>
<td>Aug 19</td>
```

Comment: I think it's really more that I'm not explaining the example thoroughly enough.  The data is defined in the way you suggest, but the template needs to know whether to display the date or the detail.  And even then, it would need to know which date to display or which detail (there are a few different date fields and a few different detail fields).  This choice is dependent on the category of the view.  I could write a long if statement but instead I chose to pass the correct field through a dictionary.

Comment: My point is that the template *doesn't* need to know whether to display the date or the detail; surely it can just display whichever one is defined?

Comment: yes.  but often times, they're both defined.  But even when they're not, the choice is dependent on the context of the view.  I'm sorry I'm not explaining this well enough.

Comment: @Ed I'll happily submit a different answer (though it still seems like my template filter gives you exactly the "determine variable type within django template' behaviour you asked for), but I think you need just need to tell us more! Your explanations aren't unclear, just incomplete.

Comment: I clarified (or further confused :-/) the question above.  I like your filter solution, but I'm not sure it works when I chain it:  {{ action|getattribute:extra_column.column|type }}

Comment: I knew suggesting that `getattribute` filter would come back to bite me soon enough... I think attempting to use both in the same template is a **GIANT RED FLAG** that you are attempting to put too much logic in the template layer. Just my `$.02`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Nevertheless, I changed return value to `type(value).__name__` as otherwise `get_type` returns `"<class 'float'>"` for float and not `"float"` and thus comparison `{% if number|get_type == 'float' %}` would always fire else-part...

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party, but I just had this problem. The solution I went for is [duck-typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), so:

```
{% if action.extra_column.year %}
  {{ action.extra_column|date:"M y" }}
{% else %}
  {{ action.extra_column }}
{% endif %}
```

Could you argue that this is definitely not the right way to do it? Probably. Will it get the job done without writing your own template filter and having even more code to maintain? Absolutely.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm way behind on this (by three years) but I just got here looking to do something similar and came up with what I think is a decent solution.

Just add a function to your models like `get_model_type` and have it return something you'd expect from each model like so:

```
class MyModelOne(models.Model):
  date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  def get_model_type(self):
    return "my_model_one"

class MyModelTwo(models.Model):
  date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  other_field = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  def get_model_type(self):
    return "my_model_two"
```

Then in your template you can easily just call that function:

```
{% if model.get_model_type == 'my_model_one' %}
  <p>Model One</p>
{% elif model.get_model_type == 'my_model_two' %}
  <p>Model Two</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's my approach:

```
@register.filter
def get_type(value):
    """ It returns variable type as a pure string name """
    return type(value).__name__
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to recognize String vs List type:

```
{%if v_1.0.1|length == 0%}
    <!--STR-->
    {{v_1}}
{%else%}     
     <!--List-->                                           
    {{v_1.0}}
{%endif%}
```