# How to know a variable is string or integer in django templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

How do I know, say 1 in django template context, is string or integer?

Comment: I think everything in django templates is either a list or a string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine variable type within django template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023112/determine-variable-type-within-django-template)