# check type in list django templates language

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have list has two types of elements let's say wether the element is element A or element B. I pass this list from the backend to the templates. In the templates I will loop for each element and then I would like to check if it is type A do this if it is type B do that. How can I do this type checking??

To clarify here is a very simple example

```
Models.py
class Type_A(models.Model):
test1 = models.CharField()

class Type_B(models.Model):
test2 = models.CharField()


Views.py 
c = {}
l = list()
l = [Type_A.objects.all(), Type_B.objects.all()]
c['list'] = shuffle(l)
return render_to_response('test.html', c , context_instance=RequestContext(request) )
```

test.html
I am looking for something like this

```
{% for x in list %}
    {% if x is Type_A %} 
       do this
    {% else %}
       do that
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the job of template filter:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12028864/1566605

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters

Answer (score 0):

`shuffle` is an inplace operation (like `sort`), it does not have a return value (it returns `None`) so this:

```
c['list'] = shuffle(l)
```

Isn't going to work, `c['list']` will be `None`:

```
>>> i = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [4,5,6]
>>> z
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> random.shuffle(z)  # Note, no return value
>>> z
[3, 6, 2, 1, 5, 4]  # z is shuffled
```

Try this version:

```
c = {}
type_a = [('A', x) for x in Type_A.objects.all()]
type_b = [('B', x) for x in Type_B.objects.all()]
combined = type_a+type_b
shuffle(combined)
c['random'] = combined
```

Then:

```
{% for t,i in random %}
   {% ifequal t "A" %}
      {{ i }} is Type "A"
   {% else %}
      {{ i }} is Type "B"
   {% endifequal %}
{% endfor %}
```

Or, you can do this:

```
{% for t,i in random %}
   {{ i }} is of type {{ t }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I don't want to show them in that order .. I want to get a random order for them .. :)