# Django - Get item from iterable in django template

Tags: python, django, templates, iterable

When iterating through a list in one of my Django templates, I'm trying to put in some if logic to say 'if the last items 'type' value is equal to the current item in the loops 'type' value, but it seems that python syntax for doing that is not allowed in a Django template. I know I can use {{ forloop.counter }}, but I can't seem to use that counter to get an item from my list at a specific index.

HTML

```
{% for repair in repairs %}
    {% if repairs[{{ forloop.counter - 1}}].type == repair.type %}<div class="col-sm-12" style="border-top: 1px solid grey; border-bottom: 1px solid grey;"><h2>{{ repair.type }}</h2></div>{% endif %}
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="{{ repair }}">
        {{ repair }}</label>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

or also

```
{% for index, repair in enumerate(repairs) %}
    {% if repairs[index - 1].type == repair.type%}<div class="col-sm-12" style="border-top: 1px solid grey; border-bottom: 1px solid grey;"><h2>{{ repair.type }}</h2></div>{% endif %}
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="{{ repair }}">
        {{ repair }}</label>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You should by able to do this by creating a template tag https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: As far as I know, Django's template syntax doesn't support `list[index]`, but rather `list.index` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [`ifchanged`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged) for this.

```
{% for repair in repairs %}
    {% ifchanged repair.type %}<div class="col-sm-12" style="border-top: 1px solid grey; border-bottom: 1px solid grey;"><h2>{{ repair.type }}</h2></div>{% endifchanged %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ahhh the power of built-in template tags. Thanks Daniel, this did exactly what I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: This checks if the _value_ of the variable has changed, not if the _type_ of the variable has changed. An important distinction.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. `ifchanged` will return `True` even if the `value` of the variable changes, while what the OP was trying to check is `type` of the variable

Comment: Sorry guys, I was probably not clear enough in my question. Type is a field of my repair object, (Screen Replacement, Button Replacement, Etc.), so I was looking for a way to use logic to see if the value of the current repair type was different than the prior repair type value

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your code.

As noted by [Justin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38399570/django-get-item-from-iterable-in-django-template/38399707#comment64207644_38399570), Django templates do not allow you to access a list element using something like `list[index]`. Instead you should do `list.index`

Django template Engine have no way to determine the type of a variable. You can, though, implement a template filter and use it to determine the type of a variable as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12028864/2801699) answer.

Also, instead of `{{ forloop.counter - 1}}`, you should do `{{ forloop.counter0 - 1}}`. `forloop.counter` gives a 1-indexed iteration of the loop whereas `forloop.counter0` gives a 0-indexed iteration of the loop.

So your final code should look something like:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_type(value):
    return type(value)

{% for repair in repairs %}
    {% if repairs.{{ forloop.counter0 - 1}}|get_type == repair|get_type %}
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="border-top: 1px solid grey; border-bottom: 1px solid grey;">
            <h2>{{ repair|get_type }}</h2>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="{{ repair }}">
                {{ repair }}
        </label>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

**Edit:** After you clarified, that 'type' is actually an attribute of the variable, here is what your code should be:

```
{% for repair in repairs %}
    {% if repairs.{{ forloop.counter0 - 1}}.type == repair.type %}
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="border-top: 1px solid grey; border-bottom: 1px solid grey;">
            <h2>{{ repair.type }}</h2>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="{{ repair }}">
                {{ repair }}
        </label>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Of course, the method suggested by [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38399570/django-get-item-from-iterable-in-django-template/38399799#38399799) is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in template tag for your use-case [`regroup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup)

```
{% regroup repairs by type as types %}
{% for type in types %}
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="border-top: 1px solid grey; border-bottom: 1px solid grey;"><h2>{{ type.grouper}}</h2></div>
    {% for repair in type.list %}
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="{{ repair }}">{{ repair }}
            </label>
         </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```