# Apply django template filter only on values of specific type

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to apply a filter *floatformat* to a value in django template **only if** the variable is numeric type, otherwise don't apply any filter at all.

for example, if I write

```
{{value|floatformat}}
```

then the filter *floatformat* should only be applied if the type of *value* is numeric (integer or float), and not in case of string.
Is there any built-in filter in django template language to get data type?

I can do that from views also, but just wished to know of I can do it in templates itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own template filter that will work with python `type()`

[More](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12028864/2614426)