# firstof usage with list variables

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have seen that list data types do not hold their structure after using `firstof` with `as`. For example:

```
{% firstof some_list some_string as value %}
```

If `some_list` is a valid list above, it gets assigned to `value`. But if I do something like `{% if pk in value %}`, it fails, even when it succeeds with `{% if pk in some_list %}`. When I print both of them:

```
{{some_list}}
{{value}}
```

they give the same output but I think list is probably not stored as list after using `firstof` with `as`. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Assigning `some_list` to `value` does not work as you expect. The resulting `value` is of the type `SafeText` and not `list`. This can be checked by using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12028864/1189656) which adds a custom template tag `get_type` to get the type of a variable.

```
{% firstof some_list as value %}
{{ some_list|get_type }}
{{ value|get_type }}
```

Which shows the following:

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'django.utils.safestring.SafeText'>
```

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#s-firstof) closer it states that `firstof`:

> **Outputs** the first argument variable that is not False.

With their example showing that `{% firstof some_list some_string %}` becomes:

```
{% if some_list %}
    {{ some_list }}
{% elif some_string %}
    {{ some_string }}
{% endif %}
```

This explains why `value` is of the `SafeText` type. The assignment simply assigns this to the variable `value`. This does not seem as a bug to me.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Do you know if this is intended behaviour or a bug?

Comment: Hmm, not entirely sure. If it assigns the output to a variable, the variable should have the type of the value being assigned (otherwise the assignment wont be of much use)?

Comment: Yes, this is the expected behavior if it was a default variable assignment. However, the Django developers decided that the behavior of `firstof` was to output the first variable which results in the type change to `SafeText`. Why this was chosen doesn't matter, but the result shows that you cannot expect the type to remain the same. So yes, the assignment is not of much use in your use case.

Answer (score 0):

I also needed that feature, to obtain first none null item (including lists) from several and assign it to a variable so I created a simple tag

```
@register.simple_tag
def firstofany(*args_list):
    i = 0
    for arg in args_list:
        if arg or i == len(args_list)-1:
            return arg
        else:
            pass
```

then in template just use

```
{% firstof some_list some_string as value %}
```

or

```
{% firstofany some_list some_string last_as_default as value %}
```

I hope it helps