# How to check type of variable in Django template

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates

Below is my sample code. I need to know the type of `weather` variable which may be List, Dictionary, or Tuple. Is there any easy way like we use `type()` in python?

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title%}
Home
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h3 class="text-center text-success">Weather Forecast!!</h3><hr>
{{weather}}
<hr>
{% for w in weather%}
{{w}}<br/>
{% endfor%}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: This should help you... https://stackoverflow.com/a/12028864/10860596

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine variable type within django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023112/determine-variable-type-within-django-template)

Comment: The above question is ok, but answers are not satisfactory!!..

Answer (score -2):

when sending variables to templates use
specific description like {{weather.sun}} or {{weather.cloudy}}

Comment: But I don't have control to the 'weather' variable. I am reading data from an URL with a python request module. Sometimes it is a dictionary of a list, sometimes it is a dictionary of dictionary, and so on.

Comment: If that's the case you can only use it in your views use type()